# using a variable in random to define max number generated

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a discord bot that lets users roll dice with the user a user-defined maximum number

```
if(cmd === `${prefix}roll`|| cmd === `${prefix}Roll`){
       let ag = cmd.slice(5);
       message.channel.send("Roll The Dice!");
       var roll = Math.floor((Math.random()* ag) + 1);
       message.channel.send(roll);
    }
```

replacing ag in "Math.random()* ag" with something like 10 will work i am just confused if how i can get it to use a var
this dose not work and dose not return any errors in the terminal

Comment: What is a sample value of `cmd`? Does it enter the `if` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the value of `ag`. it will be a string if you slide the `cmd`

I am assuming you want to create a random number between `1-6`

in that case, you can do

```
if(cmd === `${prefix}roll`|| cmd === `${prefix}Roll`){
       var ag = 6; // slice returns a string and the random generator works with a number.
       message.channel.send("Roll The Dice!");
       var roll = Math.floor((Math.random()* ag) + 1);
       message.channel.send(roll);
    }
```

**Update**

if the user specifies a number in the cmd as `!roll20` the above code will not execute at all because of the if (cmd ===`${prefix}roll`) check

```
if(cmd.startsWith(`${prefix}roll`) || cmd.startsWith(`${prefix}Roll`)){
       var ag = /\d+/g.exec(cmd); // get the digits in the value
       ag = ag ? ag[0] : 6 // check if there is a value or default to 6 
       message.channel.send("Roll The Dice!");
       var roll = Math.floor((Math.random()* ag) + 1);
       message.channel.send(roll);
    }
```

Comment: so if the user dose !roll20 how can i turn the 20 into a intiger

Comment: consider accepting the answer if it solves your problem

Comment: i will try this give me a moment